# Rebuild full path based on object keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

Assume I have this object routes which represent my website routes tree:

```
const r = {
  HOME: "start",
  ACCOUNT: {
    HOME: "account",
    PROFILE: "profile",
    ADDRESSES: {
      HOME: "addresses",
      DETAIL: ":addressId",
    },
  },
  ESHOP: {
    HOME: "eshop",
    INVOICES: "invoices",
    ORDERS: {
      HOME: "orders",
      DETAIL: ":orderId",
    },
  },
  INVENTORY: {
    HOME: "warehouse",
    CATEGORIES: {
      HOME: "categories",
      CATEGORY: {
        HOME: ":categoryId",
        PRODUCTS: {
          HOME: "products",
          PRODUCT: ":productId",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I'm trying to build a compact and elegant function to return the full path from a known object keys path, like this:

```
buildRoute(r, "r.ACCOUNT.ADDRESSES.DETAIL")
// should return this string: "start/account/addresses/:addressId"
```

or

```
buildRoute(r, "r.INVENTORY.CATEGORIES")
// should return this string: "start/warehouse/categories"
```

or

```
buildRoute(r, "r.INVENTORY.CATEGORIES.CATEGORY.PRODUCTS.PRODUCT")
// should return this string: "start/warehouse/categories/:categoryId/products/:productId"
```

Where "r" is my object routes, "HOME" is the fixed key of any path/subpath and the "slash" must be inserted in all subroutes except the last one.
Of course I'll pass the data as a string, not a value.

How can i achieve this with clean and not too long code? Typescript solution including types would be better and appreciated.

Comment: What "warehouse"? It's not in the data you shared. Also, in the 1st example, how did you decide to take HOME in the string but not PROFILE?

Comment: There may be solutions if you send in the key as a string such as `'INVENTORY.CATEGORIES.CATEGORY'`, but if you simply send in `r.INVENTORY.CATEGORIES.CATEGORY`, the _value_ of that key will be sent, and thus JS has no way of knowing what was in the upper hierarchy.

Comment: I mean there's a world where you create a copy of the data and procedurally add hierarchical values to each property of the new object so that `rCopy.INVENTORY.CATEGORIES.CATEGORY` actually contains the full string, but the question is: why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @M0nst3R my mistake, the HOME: "inventory", must be HOME: "warehouse".

Comment: @M0nst3R : as in my answer, "HOME" is a fixed key in all paths. I need this because I can't find a better way to store all of my app routes and link them inside the app (more than 300 link to be mantained and updated!). Now I'd like to found a solution to this JS problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix this

Comment: Are all the leaf values unique or can multiples leaves have the same string value?

Comment: @trincot all values of the same "level" are unique, but of course in different (nested) levels they can repeat

Comment: If values repeat at different levels, then it's impossible to do this like @technophyle indicated above.

Comment: @M0nst3R I thought it was clear that in the function I would pass the data as a string, not as a value... I'll edit the question immediately

Comment: Wow, that completely changes the question. So just split that string by "." and iterate the key names you get from that? Have you not tried anything?

Comment: Yes @trincot, I've tried splitting r.split('.') and reducing but with no great results. I'd like to write al elegant recursive function, if someone can help me.

Comment: Why recursive? Is that a requirement? It would anyhow come down to tail recursion, which is a waste of stack space when it can be written iteratively. BTW, using `reduce` should work without issue, but the split should not be on `r`, but on the second argument.

Comment: Just like @trincot said, an iterative approach fits this problem well. I don't think a recursive solution would be particularly more "elegant". Please show us your attempt to split and reduce.

Comment: Does "Typescript solution including types would be better and appreciated" mean you want the compiler to know both the valid paths and the exact outputs for those paths?  If so, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2v2bw) meet your needs? If so I could write that as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I made one with proxies, https://tsplay.dev/mb3vdW , looks like `buildProxy(r).ACCOUNT.ADDRESSES.DETAIL()` and has autocompletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the given string into its parts and then walk down the hierarchy accordingly, building the result string as you go:

```js
function buildRoute(node, path) {
    const keys = path.split(".");
    if (keys[0] != "r") throw "path must start with 'r.'";
    let result = "";
    for (const key of keys.slice(1)) {
        if (!Object.hasOwn(node, key)) throw `unknown key '${key}'`;
        result += node.HOME + "/";
        node = node[key];
    }
    return result + (typeof node === "string" ? node : node.HOME);
}

const r = {HOME: "start",ACCOUNT: {HOME: "account",PROFILE: "profile",ADDRESSES: {HOME: "addresses",DETAIL: ":addressId",},},ESHOP: {HOME: "eshop",INVOICES: "invoices",ORDERS: {HOME: "orders",DETAIL: ":orderId",},},INVENTORY: {HOME: "inventory",CATEGORIES: {HOME: "categories",CATEGORY: {HOME: ":categoryId",PRODUCTS: {HOME: "products",PRODUCT: ":productId",},},},},};

console.log(buildRoute(r, "r.ACCOUNT.ADDRESSES.DETAIL"));
// should return this string: "start/account/addresses/:addressId"
console.log(buildRoute(r, "r.INVENTORY.CATEGORIES"));
// should return this string: "start/warehouse/categories"
console.log(buildRoute(r, "r.INVENTORY.CATEGORIES.CATEGORY.PRODUCTS.PRODUCT"));
// should return this string: "start/warehouse/categories/:categoryId/products/:productId"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it compact, elegant, and to have autocompletions, use Proxy style, the same one libs like tRPC use

```
type BuildProxy<T, S extends string> =
  T extends string ? {
    (): `${S}/${T}`
  } : T extends { HOME: infer H extends string } ? {
    [K in keyof T]: BuildProxy<T[K], `${S}/${H}`>
  } & {
    (): `${S}/${H}`
  } : never

function buildProxy<T extends object>(o: T, path = ''): BuildProxy<T, ''> {
  return new Proxy(()=>{}, {
    // determines property getter
    get(f, p) {
      // if it's a string make it {HOME: string} instead
      let newO = typeof o[p] === 'string' ? { HOME: o[p] } : o[p]
      return buildProxy(newO, `${path}/${o.HOME}`)
    },
    // on call return the resulting path
    apply() {
      return `${path}/${o.HOME}`
    }
  }) as any;
}

let addr1 = buildProxy(r).ACCOUNT.ADDRESSES.DETAIL()
//  ^?
// let addr1: "/start/account/addresses/:addressId"
console.log(addr1) // logs "/start/account/addresses/:addressId"
```